# What's the order for gcc to link unresolved symbol in static library

Tags: c, gcc, shared-libraries, unix-ar

When debug the function symbols conflicts problem, I find a strange behavior of gcc i couldn't  understand, illustrate by the following sample code:

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int  main()
{
   b();
   a();
}
```

a.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
void  a(void)
{
   printf("func a in a\n");
}
```

b.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void a()
{
   printf("func a in b\n");
}
void b()
{
  printf( "func b try to call a  \n");
  a();
}
```

compile:

```
gcc -c a.c
gcc -c b.c
ar -cr liba.a a.o
ar -cr libb.a b.o
gcc main.c liba.a libb.a
```

execute:

```
./a.out
func b try to call a  
func a in b
func a in b
```

My question is :

- Why calling function `a` in `main` function is `a in b.c` instead of `a in a.c` ?
- After change the library order: `gcc main.c libb.a liba.a`, the result is the same. Why?
- Why the linker don't report symbol conflict in this situation?

Comment: Try *gcc -c main.c liba.a libb.a*

Comment: @LidongGuo i had tried , please see my second question.

Comment: Do you see that `-c` in your `main.c` compilation command line? You're not linking your program, you're only *compiling* `main.c`. Lose the `-c` for the final compile if you're also going to link. As-written your commands won't even generate an a.out, so I'm somewhat perplexed how you're running *anything*.

Comment: @WhozCraig it's a typing mistake ,i fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object files are searched for symbols to be resolved in the order of the object files' appearances, left to right, in the options passed to the linker.

Assumed the following had been run in preparation to linking:

```
gcc -c main.c
gcc -c a.c
gcc -c b.c
ar -cr liba.a a.o
ar -cr libb.a b.o
```

Then this

```
gcc -o main main.o liba.a libb.a
```

would produce:

```
libb.a(b.o): In function `a':
b.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `a'
liba.a(a.o):a.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The linker did the following:

`main.o` needs `a()` and `b ()`. First `liba` is searched: `a()` is found, `b()` isn't. So secondly `libb` is searched. `b()` is found, but also **another** `a()` leading to the linker error shown above.

If doing:

```
gcc -o main main.o libb.a liba.a
```

No errors are given and `main` is created.

The linker did the following:

`main.o` needs `a()` and `b ()`. First `libb` is searched: `a()` and `b()` are is found. As there is nothing to resolve any more <strike>`libb`</strike> `liba` isn't even looked at/in.

In the latter case the program's (`main`'s) output is:

```
func b try to call a  
func a in b
func a in b
```

---

What the linker would do/show for all other possible permutation of `main.o`, `liba.a` and `libb.a` is left as an exercise to the reader. ;-)

Comment: But I need clarified the first part of your answer 。 you could see I called b first in main.c ，so "gcc -o main main.o liba.a libb.a" don't report any errors in my case ,I used the llvm-gcc-4.2 on Mac os.

Comment: @James.xu: The order in which functions are called inside a translation unit (here: `main.c`) does not affect linking at all. The linker is **only** interested in which unit **requires** and/or **provides** which function.

Comment: On your system both variations of the final call to gcc from my answer link without errors?

Comment: yes。 without any errors reported 。 if ichanged the function order，call a first ，it report conflict errors。

Comment: Second case explanation now reads "As there is nothing to resolve anymore **libb** isn't even looked at/in", but should read: "As there is nothing to resolve anymore **liba** isn't even looked at/in".

Comment: @tne: Correct. Fixed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are not including `a` and `b` function declarations in `main.c`. if you do, you will get multiple declaration error from compiler, before it is passed to linker. You must be doing something wrong in `main.c`.

Comment: Yes， i didn’t including the  a and b function declarations, but the compiler not complaint any errors.  Actually it doesn't impact the result, i can use extern to declare the external function.

Comment: @James.xu: If you ran gcc with (most) warnings on (`-Wall`) it would proclaim about the implicit declaration of `a()` and `b()`, as well as the missing return value.